# How to properly create type using Documentum DQL

Tags: documentum-dql

Have a horrible error on simple script execution. Please help.

Error occured during query execution :[DM_QUERY_E_SYNTAX]error: "A Parser Error (syntax error) has occurred in the vicinity of:

```
create type dict_classifier_el_with_briefcase_article(
briefcase_article String(256)
)
with supertype dict_classifier_element
publish
go
```

Answer (score 0):

It was type name length limit.